# How to return interface object?

Tags: java, interface, inputstream

I have interface Transport and 2 classes Cars and Motos. Im writing in file all details about some Car or Moto.  How can i write a method 
`public static Transport inputTransport(InputStream in)`? I don`t have any info in file about type of class (Car or Motos). Should i write this info in file and after it create new Car or Moto and return it or i can write something else?

```
public interface Transport {
    public void addModel(String model, double price) throws DuplicateModelNameException;
    public void deleteModel(String model) throws NoSuchModelNameException;
    public void changeModel(String model, String new_model) throws NoSuchModelNameException,DuplicateModelNameException;
    public void changePrice(String model, double new_price) throws NoSuchModelNameException;
    public void changeType(String type);
    public String getType();
    public int getNumber();
    public String getPrice(String model) throws NoSuchModelNameException;
    public String[] getAllModels();
    public double[] getAllPrices();
}
```

```
class Cars implements Transport{

    private String type;
    private Models[] cars;
    private int number;

    Cars(String type, int number){
        this.type = type;
        this.number = number;
        cars = new Models[number];
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++){
            cars[i] = new Models("default", Double.NaN);
        }
    } ...
```

```
class Motos implements Transport {
    private int count = 0;
    private String type;

    Motos(String type){
        this.type = type;
    }...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ObjectOutputStream and save your objects to a file, then you use an ObjectInputStream to import the objects and this InputStream will now the exact class of your object.

I wrote a small example Program which should get you started.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();

        save(a);

        C c = load();

        System.out.println(c.getClass()); // prints "A"

        if (c instanceof A) {
            System.out.println("is of class A");
            A loaded = (A) c;// you can now use this object
            System.out.println(a.someMethod());
        } else if (c instanceof B) {
            System.out.println("is of class B");
            B loaded = (B) c;
        } else {
            System.out.println("should not occur");
        }
    }

    private static C load() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("f.txt"));
        C s = (C) in.readObject();
        in.close();
        return s;
    }

    private static void save(C c) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        final FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("f.txt");
        final ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
        out.writeObject(c);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }

}

class A implements C {
    // serialVersion is the version of the clas, so if you save the object with
    // serialVersion 1 and then change something, change this version to two, so you
    // get an error if you are trying to load "obsolete" objects
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "A";
    }

    public String someMethod() {
        return "someMethod";
    }
}

class B implements C {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "B";
    }

    public String someOtherMethod() {
        return "someOtherMethod";
    }
}

interface C extends Serializable { //Objects saved to a File have to be Serializable
    String getName();
}
```

Comment: i can not use objects... I can use only DataInputStream for this programm.